# Structuring a jar?

Tags: java, jar, package

NOTE: yes, minecraft has a specific coder pack, but it doesn't work for mac or linux (something to do with the python script portability)

While attempting to mod the main java jar file (minecraft.jar) i noticed it has an unusual structure, which im unsure on how to build. It contains all the objects (or the classes which are frequently called) at the top of the [name for structure of jar], and these, when decompiled, didnt belong to any packages. Whereas the files which were executed did belong to packages.

so my question is, how do i structure a jar file like this myself, with an IDE (eclipse/intelliJ)?

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is create some classes in the default package (no `package` declaration in the .java file).

Comment: ok, thats probably what would happen, but, because i imported the files as a seperate module (using intelliJ) they don't seem to be detected as default packages, maybe i need to rethink the way i set up the project. I need to be able to import the project into anyones minecraft folder, but unless i lay the project out exactly as notch did, it will generate a classnotdeffounderror.

Comment: k, sort of complete now, it took the project as is when i rename the actual source as the src folder